# Sending anonymous data from android

Tags: android

I am currently trying to design a game for android.  I am close to putting it out to family and friends for beta testing.  I would like to have it automatically send me data as to how often they play it and where they die so that I can ensure that the levels are created  correctly.  Is this possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You might have a look at [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/), a mobile analytics library, that allows you to get basic information on usage & co. You may as well define custom events (e.g. killed in level x) in order to track custom information.

Comment: Yep, Flurry is the way to go here.